# Ensuring some emails arrive in order while others arrive randomly

Tags: c#, multithreading, email

I'm trying to send multi email at the same time by using multithreading approach. Here my description:

I have 5 emails need to send randomly:

```
Email1
Email2
Email3
Email4
Email5
```

Maybe Email5 will be sent first then Email1 or Email4.

I got a new requirement of my customer: Email1,2,3 maybe sent randomly but Email4 must be sent before Email5 (User get an Email4 before Email5, I meant some emails need to be sent by order and some randomly).

I don't know how to deal with this problem by using multithreading approach.

Comment: Did you mean that Email5 must be the next after Email4, or that Email5 could arrive at anytime after Email4, while others fall between?

Comment: The order you send emails in does not guarantee the same delivery order. Most emails are batch-delivered by the sending / receiving mail server, and many email clients sort by delivery date, not sent date. I know this doesn't answer your question, hence my posting as a comment, but it's something you should keep in mind.

Comment: @p.campbell: yes, Email5 must be the next after Email4

Comment: @Chris: I see, anyway as long as the Email5 must be sent after sending Email4

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Task Parallel Library this kind of requirement is easy to meet using [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx)

```
  var firstTask = new Task(() => SendEmail(4));
  var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith((t) => SendEmail(5));
  firstTask.Start();
```

An alternative approach not using TPL could use a `LinkedList` to chain together emails that must be sent in sequence.  Create a `Queue<LinkedList<Email>>`.  Your worker threads consume the `Queue` items, picking off a `LinkedList`, then chaining down it sending each `Email`.

Comment: Thank you but how could I do the same way in .net 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning priorities? But unless you actually hold multiple connections to the mail server, your mails will be sent out in sequence anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Associate a semaphore with each email and have the thread for email 5 aquire and wait on the semaphore for email 4 before it sends its email. Each semaphore should be initialized with zero permits and the threads should release one permit when they have sent their email. You can also do this with mutexes.

Comment: This is useful only if you know that it is homework of sort and one is expected to use semaphores. Otherwise this approach will not scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a worker pattern split the work-queue into sequenced and non sequenced (two work-queues) and have the sequence queue only be served by one thread.